# Running multiple scenarios in one feature, only one scenario invoked in Karate version 1.0.1

Tags: karate

When I tried to run 3 scenarios in one feature, only one scenarios succeeded. and getting error from console:

````
classpath:com/api/automation/getRequest/healthCheck.feature:6
17:24:45.772 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: qa 
17:24:45.773 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.intuit.karate - classpath:com/api/automation/getRequest/healthCheck.feature:6
* callonce read('classpath:karate-config.js')
Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.forEach(java.util.function.BiConsumer)" because "result.vars" is null
classpath:com/api/automation/getRequest/healthCheck.feature:6```\



I'm using ParallelBuilder

 ```public class ParallelBuilder {
    
    @Test
    public void executeKarateTest() {
        Builder aRunner = new Builder();
        aRunner.path("classpath:com/api/automation/getRequest");
        Results result = aRunner.parallel(2);
        System.out.println("Total Feature =>" + result.getFeaturesTotal());
        System.out.println("Total Scenaorios =>" + result.getScenariosTotal());
        System.out.println("Passed Scenaorios =>" + result.getScenariosPassed());
        
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, result.getScenariosFailed(),"There are some Failed Scenarios");
    }```

Could someone please help me out here? Thanks in advance !
````

Comment: sounds like a bug in Karate or no one can help you remotely with examples like this, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue